# No results when using a web API

Tags: php, xml, usps

I'm attempting to pull an XML page from the U.S. Postal Service (USPS) rate calculator, using PHP.  Here is the code I am using (with my API login and password replaced of course):

```
<?
$api = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request ".
       "USERID=\"MYUSERID\" PASSWORD=\"MYPASSWORD\"><Revision/><Package ID=\"1ST\">".
       "<Service>FIRST CLASS</Service><FirstClassMailType>PARCEL</FirstClassMailType>".
       "<ZipOrigination>12345</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>54321</ZipDestination>".
       "<Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>9</Ounces><Container/><Size>REGULAR</Size></Package></RateV4Request>";

$xml_string = file_get_contents($api); 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
?>
```

Pretty straightforward.  However it never returns anything.  I can paste the URL directly into my browser's address bar:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4RequestUSERID="MYUSERID" PASSWORD="MYPASSWORD"><Revision/><Package ID="1ST"><Service>FIRST CLASS</Service><FirstClassMailType>PARCEL</FirstClassMailType><ZipOrigination>12345</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>54321</ZipDestination><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>9</Ounces><Container/><Size>REGULAR</Size></Package></RateV4Request>
```

And it returns the XML I need, so I know the URL is valid.  But I cannot seem to capture it using PHP.  Any help would be tremendously appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One thing is that you need to URL encode the XML that you are sending to the service. The browser will do that for you automatically, but `file_get_contents` won't.

Try this:

```
 $param = urlencode("<RateV4Request ".
   "USERID=\"MYUSERID\" PASSWORD=\"MYPASSWORD\"><Revision/><Package ID=\"1ST\">".
   "<Service>FIRST CLASS</Service><FirstClassMailType>PARCEL</FirstClassMailType>".
   "<ZipOrigination>12345</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>54321</ZipDestination>".
   "<Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>9</Ounces><Container/><Size>REGULAR</Size></Package></RateV4Request>");

 $api = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML="
        .$param;

 ... then the rest of the code
```

If that doesn't help, make sure you have error reporting activated so you get a response if `file_get_contents` has an error.